# Отследить обновление URL | JS

Tags: javascript

Делаю расширение (Chrome) для [сайта с расписанием](https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/group/623p). Я хочу в JS отследить выбор расписания другой группы. Проблема в том, что сайт написан на `blazor SPA`.

Я заметил, что при выборе группы, обновляется URL.
Например, изначально я открыл расписание группы 623п, и URL был такой: `https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/group/623p`, после этого я выбрал группу 512 и URL стал следующим: `https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/group/512`.

Пытался отследить изменение URL так:

```
window.addEventListener('locationchanged', function () {
    console.log('url changed');
});
```

и так:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    console.log('url changed');
});
```

и даже так:

```
var pushState = history.pushState;
history.pushState = function () {
    pushState.apply(history);
    console.log('url changed');
};
```

Однако, ничего из этого не помогло.

Comment: как именно меняется урл? добавь пример с какого на какой

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: А ты уверен, что там нет перехода по ссылке? UPDATE: Нет, там SPA.

Comment: Твой скрипт выполняется в контексте страницы? Может в контексте расширения потыкать chrome.tabs?

Comment: а разве вариант с pushState не сработал? Именно он вызывается

Comment: @Grundy, так у него и вызов кривой, и не факт, что вообще скрипт на странице исполняется...

Comment: Примитивно, но можно прикаждом клике сверять url с первым значением переменной и обновлять её при необходимости

Comment: @Николай можно, конечно, но я обновляю html страницы, не хотелось бы это делать при каждом клике

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var pushState = history.pushState;
> history.pushState = function () {
>     pushState.apply(history);
>     console.log('url changed');
> };
> ```

Ну кто ж так патчит? Надо

```
pushState.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: наверное, `this, arguments`?

Comment: всё равно не срабатывает

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, да, раскладку не сменил. Проверь, в каком контексте выполняется скрипт. Из консоли браузера работает.

Comment: Я пытался вызвать его как из content script, так и из background

Answer (score 0):

Основываясь на [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957319/how-to-listen-for-url-change-with-chrome-extension) ответе, и изменив его под `Manifest V3`, у меня вышло следующее:

- manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["scripts/content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    ...
}
```

- scripts/background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // отправляем сообщение, когда изменилась URL
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            message: 'url-changed',
            url: changeInfo.url
        });
    }
});
```

- scripts/content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // реагируем сообщение об изменении URL
    if (request.message === 'url-changed') {
        console.log('new URL is ' + request.url);
    }
});
```